# wsdl file generated for all lists or single list + SharePoint

Tags: php, web-services, sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2007

I generated a .wsdl file by using:

```
sharepoint.url/subsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL.
```

And downloaded it locally where I am running the web-service with SOAP client. Is it fine if I am running the web-service on my local server and using the generated .wsdl file to retrieve SharePoint lists which run on a Windows Server available through LAN. Now, .wsdl file which gets generated is for a single list or multiple lists? My problem is, I keep getting the following error:

```
HTTPFault string: Unauthorized
```

I have enabled basic authentication in IIS on Windows Server also but the error remains.